# What if Bitcoin gets to the point that all the coins have been mined?

Tags: transactions

What if Bitcoin gets to the point that all the coins have been mined? There will be lots of transactions and no one to process them. My question is who will do all the transaction processing when mining no longer pays.

Answer (score 2):

[From the bitcoin wiki](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Transaction_fees):

> It is envisioned that over time the cumulative effect of collecting transaction fees will allow somebody creating new blocks to "earn" more bitcoins than will be mined from new bitcoins created by the new block itself. This is also an incentive to keep trying to create new blocks even if the value of the newly created block from the mining activity is zero in the far future.

When you make a transaction and set a TX fee, that goes to the bitcoin miner.